# Django profile image is incorrectly displaying the logged in user's image (on every profile)

Tags: python, django, templates, view, model

Any assistance in this would be much appreciated.

I extended the Django User model with a OneToOne relationship to another model called UserProfile, which contains an ImageField called profile_pic.

Settings for root media folder are setup correctly in settings.py and referred to in root urls.py.

Something is incorrect with the class-based view, a generic ListView to display a user's product posts, or I'm incorrectly referring to the profile_pic in the template.

Any ideas on how to display each user's profile image on their associated userprofile? Currently, when a user is logged in, his/her image is displaying on every profile. Using Django 3.1.2

**models.py**

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    profile_pic = models.ImageField(default='default_profile_pic.jpg', upload_to='profile_pics')

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "User Profiles"

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.user.username} UserProfile'
    
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

**views.py**

```
class ProfileListView(ListView):
    model = Product
    template_name = 'users/profile.html'
    context_object_name = 'products' 
    paginate_by = 12

    def get_queryset(self):
        user = get_object_or_404(User, username=self.kwargs.get('username'))
        return Product.objects.filter(user=user).order_by('-creation_date')
```

**profile.html**

```
{% if user.userprofile.profile_pic %}
        <img class="rounded-circle" src="{{ user.userprofile.profile_pic.url }}" alt="">
        {% else %}
        <img class="rounded-circle" src="media/default_profile_pic.jpg" alt="">
        {% endif %}
```

Comment: `user` is automatically populated with the currently logged in user when you have `django.core.context_processors.auth` in the list of your context processors. Your view is named `ProfileList` but it returns `Product` objects and the context variable name is `products`. You don't define a `user` yourself.

Comment: Thanks @Selcuk I appreciate the insights. Would you suggest I change the ProfileList model = UserProfile and the context variable to userprofile? If so, I won't have access to the products. What might be an efficient way to define the user while making their Products available in the ProfileList view? The Product model has a ForeignKey relationship to User. Thanks again. This is twisting my mind a bit.

Comment: I'll figure this out. Going to rework the ProfileListView.

Comment: It depends on what you want from this view. If it is designed to return a list of products belonging to a specified user (but not necessarily the logged in user) then keep the code (maybe rename it to `ProductListView` for consistency) and use `{{ product.user.userprofile.profile_pic.url }}` in your template.